# Difference between apple-mobile-web-app-capable and apple-touch-fullscreen | iPhone / iOS meta tags

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, meta-tags, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a question for which I couldn't find answer neither in google or directly at apple developer forum.

What is the exact difference between:

```
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
```

and

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They behave the same way, at least for now. `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` is the only version mentioned in [Safari documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), so I would stick with it. It looks to me as if `apple-touch-fullscreen` was used in early demos/previews, so it was left working later when the SDK got actually released, but the preferred version is the one documented.